# Yielding alternate values in iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given a number of iterables , I need to produces all the values in the first iterable, followed by all in the second, ... , all values in the last iterable alternatively.

**Example** :

```
for i in alternate('abcde','fg','hijk'): 
      print(i,end=' ')
```

It is expected to produce the values

```
a f h b g i c
```

I know to print all the characters in sequence like

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'
```

Here is the code:

```
def alternate(*args):
    for iterable in args:
        for item in iterable:
            yield item
```

But how do I yield them alternatively?

Comment: What python version?

Comment: @ReutSharabani Python 3.

Comment: What's the expected output of `alternate('a', 'bcdefg', 'hijkl')` for instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to terminate on shortest list use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

```
def alternate(*args):
    # note: python 2 - use izip_longest
    for iterable in zip(*args):
        for item in iterable:
            if item is not None:
                yield item
```

If you want to use all items use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue.

```
def alternate(*args):
    # note: python 2 - use izip_longest
    for iterable in itertools.zip_longest(*args):
        for item in iterable:
            if item is not None:
                yield item
```

Note that it skips `None` values (can be changed with `fillvalue`).

Without `itertools`:

```
def alternate(*args):
    max_len = max(map(len, args))
    for index in range(max_len):
        for lst in args:
            try:
                yield lst[index]
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

To stop on first "missing" item:

```
def alternate(*args):
    index = 0
    while True:
        for lst in args:
            try:
                yield lst[index]
            except IndexError:
                return
        index += 1
```

And if you're using generators (or iterators) you'll get `StopIteration` when one of them is done, so you can use `iter` to create a general function:

```
def alternate(*args):
    iters = [iter(lst) for lst in args]
    while True:
        for itr in iters:
            try:
                yield next(itr)
            except StopIteration:
                return
```

Comment: Can there be a way without using izip_longest(*args) ?

Comment: @Hacker688 `itertools` has been in the standard library since Python 2.3.

Comment: @Hacker688 that question is answered by the documentation link as well as a very simple check in your python-interpreter that takes 5 seconds.

Comment: @Hacker688 izip_longest was renamed in python3. in python2 zip_longest creates lists, not iterators. Fixed in answer: http://ideone.com/xOQhMi

Comment: @Reut Sharabani But output is [a f h b g i c j d k e]  and NOT [a f h b g i c]

Comment: @Hacker688 why would it be `a f h b g i c`?

Comment: @Hacker688 , sorry, I thought you want to use all items. Added the easier solution using built-in `zip`: http://ideone.com/3A6G67.

Comment: @ReutSharabani There is no character in second string

Comment: @Hacker688 why `c`? If you trim all to have length of 2 `c` is not yielded.

Comment: @ReutSharabani But if we see c is printed and then we notice that there is no corresponding letter in second string

Comment: @Hacker688 check last version :)

Comment: @Hacker688 added code for this as well, note that you need to use one code for lists and another code for generators. You can use `iter(lst)` if you list is `lst` to iterate a list using `next` thus making the last function general.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Still runtime error http://ideone.com/E2sOpX I need only one function for all type of parameters

Comment: @Hacker688 I've added the use of `iter` to create an iterator regardless of the argument, so as long as your argument is a list of iterables it should work (see last version in answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76363/discussion-between-hacker688-and-reut-sharabani).

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.  It works for any input, it won't trip up if one of the items is `None`.  It uses the builtin `itertools` module, and will work on python 3.x and python 2.7 with only the builtin python modules.  It is based on the [`roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) function from the Python `itertools` documentation:

```
from itertools import cycle

def roundrobin_shortest(*iterables):
    "roundrobin_shortest('ABCD', 'EF', 'GHI') --> A E G B F H C"
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while True:
        try:
            for inext in nexts:
                yield inext()
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

This version works basically the same, but is a bit shorter:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

def roundrobin_shortest(*iterables):
    "roundrobin_shortest('ABCD', 'EF', 'GHI') --> A E G B F H C"
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    yield from chain.from_iterable(inext() for inext in nexts)
```

And a version without itertools:

```
def roundrobin_shortest(*iterables):
    "roundrobin_shortest('ABCD', 'EF', 'GHI') --> A E G B F H C"
    items = [iter(item) for item in iterables]
    while True:
       try:
           for it in items:
               yield next(it)
       except StopIteration:
           break
```

You can use any of these like so:

```
>>> for i in roundrobin_shortest('abcde','fg','hijk'): 
...     print(i, end=' ')
...
a f h b g i c
```

Or here is a simpler one-liner

```
>>> from itertools import chain, cycle
>>> iters = ('abcde','fg','hijk')
>>> res = chain.from_iterable(j() for j in cycle(iter(j).__next__ for j in iters))
>>> print(' '.join(res))
a f h b g i c
```